# Facing issue Appium to start

Tags: android, ios

Facing issue, app is opens and closes

[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'in.fybr'

[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code 253

[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments never checked in

[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -

Answer (score 0):

This means the app your trying to run isnt valid to run on your target phone.

for iOS there is a pre-requisite that you should resign your app with a developer profile which consists of the device ID.

so you should get a **developer certificate** which has your device id added and a **mobile provisioning file**.

Now install an app called **iResign** in which you need to give the app , point the deveoper certificate, mobile provisioning file and it will resign the app.

Now this app will run on your target phone (sice its signed with the dev profile which has added your device id)